# Autofilling Excel formulas that contain data arranged in a different orientation

Tags: microsoft-excel

Basically I have a grid with rows that contain a win or a loss for two teams round by round in sets of 3 games per round (shown on the left in the screenshot). However, I'd like to sum the total wins per round and then declare a team a winner for that round, (the grid on the right). Since these are oriented in a different direction, dragging to autofill the rest of the cells in the "round winners" grid simply moves the specified array to the right by 1 (as it should, by design). So I'm basically wondering if there's a way to tell Excel to increase the row number in the equation instead of the column letter.

On top of that, since each round has 3 games, I would need the solution to include a way to skip 3 rows each time I copy the formula to the next cell.

What I'm trying to accomplish:
[image: screenshot of what I'm trying to accomplish]

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Office 365

Answer (score 0):

*With little modification your issue can be fixed:*

**:Caveat:**

I've altered the format of source data has a logic behind.

- Since each round has 3 matches, so the first column is **Match Number**, followed by the **Team Name** & **Round Number**.
- Winning team gets 1 point, and the looser gets 0.

[image]

- Enter this formula in cell W18 & fill across

  ```
  =IF($V18=$S$17,SUMPRODUCT(($U$18:$U$29=W$17)*($S$18:$S$29)),IF($V18=$T$17,SUMPRODUCT(($U$18:$U$29=W$17)*($T$18:$T$29))))
  ```
- Cell AA18 has this one `=SUM(W18:Z18)`.

**N.B.**

- For a good look & better understanding, I've used only 4 round, you can increase them as per need.
- This may be extended to Count Win, Loss & Draw matches also.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.